# Taking only the first 100 resulted rows each time when a criteria is True

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone know how to take only the first 100 resulted rows each time when  this is True?:

```
=COUNTIFS(R2C9:R50000C9,RC[-1])>30?
```

I have a sheet with 9 columns `A-I`. The column `I` that is `Amount` has values from `1-1600 kg` and only increases. At some times remains stable for further than 30 seconds. I would like to collect these data when the amount is stable, but I only need the first 100 rows of every time when the amount is stable. I don't want only the first 100 rows when the criteria is `True`, because in this way it gives me only the 100 rows of the first time when the amount("I") is stable.

Thank you in advance.

This is my code:

```
Sub philoly_3()
    '
    ' philoly_3 Macro
    '

    Sheets("Graph data").Select
    Range("J1").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Criteria"
    Range("J2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(R2C9:R50000C9,RC[-1])>30"
    Range("J2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J50000")
    Range("J2:J50000").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Style = "Input"
    Range("F2").Select
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$50000").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="TRUE"
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range("A1:I1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("All moments").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("F2").Select
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Sheets("All moments").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("All moments").Move Before:=Sheets(1)
    Sheets("Graph data").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$50000").AutoFilter Field:=10
    Range("I50000").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Range("I2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("B2").Select

    philoly_11

End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: I hardly recommend to read a tutorial on how to avoid `.Select` and `Selection.` (you will find many on Google). Then refactor your code and it will get **a lot** shorter, better readable, better understandable and **faster**! This helps at first yourself **a lot** especially when you are a beginner, it is the best to learn how to avoid these 2 as fast as possible. It will save you so much time. Also it is more likely that someone else reads your code and helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will follow it.

Comment: Why do VBA at all? Is a formula ok?

Comment: What do you mean? I have to do it in a vba because this is my main resource in the company and they needed in excel and also to understand it and modify it, in the future.

Comment: @PhilolyTsopel I really suggest to refactor your code (as already mentioned) and update the original question if you are waiting for an good answer here. I think most people don't want to spend their time reading that spaghetti code. If you updated your code explain well what it already does, where it throws errors or what you expect instead.